# Implementing article revision history for Java based web application

Tags: java, revision, database-versioning

Any ideas of how **best** i can implement article revision history for a Java based web application and save it in AuditLog

StackOverflow already has such a feature allowing one to see the differences from one version to another, almost like SVN clients.

This is more of a design than implementation question.

addition: How would one display these changes on the web page?

addition: Proposed solution

```
Article
--------------------------------
    Integer id
    String title
    String body
    List<Tag> tags
    AppUser createdBy
    Date createdDate

AuditLog
--------------------------------
    Integer id
    Integer objectId
    Operation operation // enum with UPDATE and DELETE. I won't audit an insert
    Date createdDate
    AppUser createdBy
    String class
    String revisionXML
    String comment
```

A [Hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html) [Interceptor](https://www.hibernate.org/318.html) will intercept
the save process and use [Castor XML](http://www.castor.org/reference/html-single/index.html) to create an XML string of the old object.

The class and id is used to get the revisions of a particular object.

[google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/API) will be used for creating HTML diff files

Comment: from the answers, i will be using DaisyDiff. SVNKit is meant for data in an SVN server. From JackRabbit's API i didn't see any interfaces for get document / node diffs.

Comment: spotted a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923398/how-show-revision-history-like-revisions

Comment: more; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281/database-design-for-revisions ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762405/database-data-versioning

Comment: For those reading this later. i have just spotted Hibernate Envers(http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html), hibernate will take care of version of you entites, and you can use google-diff-match to generate the actual diffs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution would be to use a database or storage which already supports versions, for example [Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/).

If that's not an option, then you must decide where you want to store the articles. On the file system? Then make each article a directory and save the revisions as numbers (00001, 00002, etc.) and put the number of the last revision in a special file (like `current`). Then you can quickly find out how many versions there are (just look into `current`) and go forward and back.

If you use a database, then add a version number field to the article table and add a second table or a flag which says which one the current version is. You could also select with `max(version)` but those SQL constructs tend to be pretty ugly and confusing. It's much more simple to save this information elsewhere.

[EDIT] To generate diffs, look at this project: [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch)

Comment: i will be using a MySQL database, how about syntax highlighting showing the differences (additions, deletions, ...) on the web page?

Comment: taking a look an Apache Jackrabbit

Comment: On top of the data store, you need a diff tool. See this project: http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

Comment: @Aaron - thanks, i also noticed DaisyDiff: http://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/ for HTML diffs

Answer (score 1):

I would use an existing VCS (for instance, SVN) under the hood. There you have the revision history - all that's left to make is an interface from your app to the VCS.

Comment: If you go this route, look into SvnKit (http://svnkit.com/) a Java Svn library, though I would recommend using Jackrabbit (JCR) as the other answer mentions since it will also do a lot more for you.